# ¿Como asignar una variable en Javascript de una peticion AJAX?

Tags: ajax, laravel

Tengo una super incognita y eh investigado por internet y nada que doy con esto necesito asignar el resultado de una peticion AJAX a una variable aqui el codigo,

```
    var self = this;

    self.on('mount',function(){
        __clienteautocomplete();
    })

    function __clienteautocomplete(){
        var cliente = $("#cliente"),
            options = {
                url: function(q){
                    return baseUrl('factura/findCliente?q=' + q);
                },
            getValue : "CL_primer_nombre",
            list: {
                onClickEvent: function() {
                    var e = cliente.getSelectedItemData();
                    self.id = e.CL_ID;
                    self.apellido = e.CL_primer_apellido;
                    self.cedula = e.CL_CI;
                    self.direccion = e.CL_direccion;
                    self.estado=getciudad(e.CL_estado);
                    self.ciudad = e.CL_ciudad;
                    self.update();
                }
            }
        };

        function getciudad($id){
            var resultado;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/estado/'+$id,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(key,value){
                        resultado = value;
                        return resultado;
                    });
                },
            });
        }

        $("#cliente").easyAutocomplete(options);
    }
```

todo esto porque necesito que el valor que llega en e.CL_estado  consultarlo en la BSD para obtener el nombre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es porque resulta que el metodo ajax es en realidad una función. Además, en tu caso, ese return figura dentro de otra función anidada (el each que tienes en el success), luego , tu return no es lo que va a devolver tu función "getciudad".

Para resolverlo, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
    function getciudad($id){
        var resultado;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/estado/'+$id,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key,value){
                    resultado = value;
                });
            },
        });
        return resultado;
    }
```

Colocando la variable resultado, fuera del metodo ajax y el each, el return se convierte en el return asociado a la funcion "getCiudad".

No obstante, ten cuidado (o ten en cuenta) que la variable resultado va a contener el valor de la ultima iteración que se realiza en el bucle each, vale? ya que estas machacando el valor de "resultado" en cada iteración. Si lo que quieres es recoger todos los valores de dicha iteración, deberías ir agregandolos a un array, vale?

Debes también tener en cuenta la asincronía de javascript, vale? En ese caso, quizas te interese hacerlo sincrono. (con async:false)

Comment: igual me aparece valor indefinido :s

Comment: puedes poner un console.log de los valores que te va devolviendo el metodo success?

Comment: no me deja , me aparece que no se espera el . de console.log y nada :c

Comment: Gracias!!! con el async: false  sirvio :D